# Qual o recomendável? Usar o Stack Snippet ou outra ferramenta?

Tags: debate, comportamento, stack-snippets

Como todo sabemos, aqui na própria rede existe o recurso de `Stack Snippets` para poder rodar `JS+HTML+CSS` no próprio corpo da pergunta e da resposta, mas também existem muitas outras opções, tipo o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ou o [codepen](http://codepen.io/), algumas vezes opto por usar o fiddle quando o próprio AP optou por usa-lo mas sempre que possível tento trazer os códigos para o `snippets`, gostaria de saber... Devemos incentivar aos novos usuários a utilizar a ferramenta própria do site?

Comment: Eu acho que sim, desde que traga algum proveito para a pergunta. Se a pergunta for só com JS não há necessidade de o usar.

Comment: Mas por exemplo, nessa pergunta do @WallaceMaxters: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77622/14262, apesar de a pergunta ser clara, e não haver necessidade de ter algo visual, pelo meno **na minha** opinião, acho bacana ter um exemplo funcional.... Muitas vezes me vejo perdido ao tentar aprender algum `framework` ou alguma técnica de programação sem nenhum exemplo de quem desenvolveu

Comment: Eu uso o jsFiddle porque é mais fácil de testar e acrescentar código. Acho que a ferramenta da SE é util mas não é tão flexivel como o jsFiddle ou codepen. Se o AP colocar um jsFiddle é bem mais fácil/rápido ajudar do que se colocar só o Stack snippet. Daí que eu conituo a incetivar o uso de ferramentas externas.

Comment: Nesse caso acho que depende de cada um por o exemplo ou não. Acho que nessa pergunta especifica não há necessidade de ter o exemplo, mas compreendo que se faça.

Comment: Concordo com a resposta do @sergio. Claro que usar a ferramenta do SO não irá fazer mal. Porém, utilizar alguma ferramenta "melhor", não irá trazer problemas. Mas creio que a melhor opção seja criar os dois. Pois, se alguém está querendo ajuda, isso não impede de perder 5 minutos para criar um exemplo em alguma ferramenta.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Qual o recomendável?

```
Depende.
```

Na minha opinião seria bom ter sempre um jsFiddle ou CodePen, e complementarmente um Stack snippet (pelo menos com a funcionalidade que tem hoje).

O Stack Snippet é útil e veio trazer algo que claramente faltava no site. Mas ainda tem limitações a meu ver.

Existem duas coisas importantes no que respeita a tais ferramentas.

- possibilitar correr o código
- possibiltar uma cópia para continuar a desenvolver

A meu ver ambas essas funcionalidades têm limitações no Stack snippet.

O Stack snippet permite correr o código, mas só na pergunta. Se eu quiser correr o código fora so SO isso não é possivel. Dá para clicar em "página toda" mas ao copiar o url isso não reproduz a funcionalidade *correr o código em modo "página toda"*.

O Stack snippet permite criar uma cópia, mas só para inserir numa nova resposta. Se eu quiser copiar o código e continuar a desenvolver para meu uso próprio isso não é possível. Isto é uma limitação para quem quer usar conteúdo e continuar a desenvolver, mas também para quem quer ajudar pois para acrescentar o código que resolve o problema e testar, então é mais prático se tiver um jsFiddle por exemplo.

Comment: Com essa de "correr o código", no início achei que estava falando de _scroll_. auheuaheuaehuae Aqui geralmente usamos "rodar o código" ou "executar". :P

Answer (score -3):

O jsfiddle esta com erros internos, de sintaxe, não recomendo! o codepen é muito melhor, mais estavel! Entre o jsfiddle e Stack Snippets, recomendo o Stack Snippets!