# A mensagem passada pela comunidade sobre os links nas respostas não é a mais correta

Tags: debate, respostas

Eu tenho a ideia que a comunidade do StackExchange em geral anda a "evangelizar" (ou melhor, já evangelizou) a ideia de que os recursos externos podem desaparecer.

E sim, podem. As pessoas podem também apagá-los, modificá-los, podem morrer e deixar de os manter, podem ficar desactualizados. Mas isto tudo também acontece **aqui**.

Mas no meu ponto de vista a comunidade está a focar-se no problema errado.
Já vi muitas vezes comentários a focarem-se no problema que os links podem desaparecer, quando na verdade o problema é que a resposta está incompleta.

Eu não quero que ninguém na comunidade se preocupe em relação ao fato de recursos externos desaparecerem.

Se a resposta foi feita neste momento e usa um recurso é porque esse recurso existe neste momento e **não devemos assumir absolutamente nada sobre ele, especialmente que ele vai desaparecer**. Ele está lá porque quem respondeu o usou para consultar informação. Ele também pode ser usado pelo AP para obter outras informações relacionadas.

O que a comunidade quer é que a sua resposta tenha informação suficiente, vinda do seu conhecimento, ou fontes que consultou, de forma a melhorar a qualidade da sua resposta.

Por favor, eu apelo a todos os membros da comunidade para deixarem de comentar algo do género.

> Por favor inclua informação do recurso mencionado, ele pode deixar de existir.

Em vez optem por reforçar que a resposta está incompleta! Algo como:

> A sua resposta está incompleta. Por favor inclua o conteúdo do recurso que considera relevante, de forma a completar a sua resposta.

---

**A minha intenção é somente melhorar a mensagem passada pela comunidade.** Estou apenas a propor que a comunidade use mensagens diferentes e tenho noção do funcionamento da comunidade em relação aos links na resposta.

Comment: Os exemplos citados, em geral, não se vão mesmo. Esses até são aceitáveis nesse ponto. Outro eu já não sei. Você pode provar isso? Você se responsabiliza se for embora? Vive acontecendo casos de *links* que foram embora. Se tem um conteúdo aqui que independa do *link* sem problemas, se a solução estava no *link*, a resposta não existe mais. De fato o ponto de ir embora não é o mais importante, é um agravante para o fato de não ter a informação na resposta. No geral, a sugestão é válida, o importante é termos respostas no site.

Comment: Relacionado: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/91)

Comment: @bigown Você se responsabiliza se for embora? Eu não quero que ninguém, eu inclusivé eu se preocupe com isso. Este é o meu dilema. E por isso a resposta é sim!

Mas essa não é a mensagem ideal que a comunidade quer transmitir, mas sim que a resposta deve ser completa e ter informação do recurso. Assim não posso ser acusado de ter deixado uma resposta que não responde à pergunta.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Concordo que a mensagem pode ser melhorada, mas não invalida a preocupação que conteúdos externos vão se embora. Em geral, nós moderadores analisamos caso a caso antes de converter em comentário ou remover um resposta que seja só *link*. Não há um entendimento definitivo que tudo que seja só um *link* não é uma resposta, ainda que algumas pessoas até achem que seja. Então sem um caso específico para analisar eu não poderia dizer nem que sim, nem que não.

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Comment: É desse comentário que falas?

Comment: @JorgeB. Não falei de nenhum comentário em especifico. Apenas tenho a ideia que a comunidade está a passar a mensagem errada, algumas vezes. O problema não é o link deixar de funcionar mas sim a resposta não estar completa.

Comment: Eu acho que uma mensagem como aquela está boa para perceber. O problema também é o link deixar de funcionar, depende do caso.

Comment: "_Blogs, repositórios on-line, entre outros, muitos deles não se vão embora! Pelos menos não antes desta comunidade!_" para que toda essa raiva meu jovem? Mais fácil qualquer doc desaparecer do que o SO. Olha a magnitude de onde estamos, isso sim é algo sólido.

Comment: Não entendi a rejeição. Apesar de concordar que a probabilidade do recurso desaparecer ser meio que irrelevante quando o assunto é resposta incompleta, além de ser muito difícil de julgar, acho que a mensagem sugerida é muito mais didática e proveitosa do que a que temos hoje. Posso não concordar com todas as premissas do AP, mas acho que a sugestão é bastante válida.

Comment: @Gabe eu acredito que por ele afirmar que os recursos externos não vão desaparecer, sendo que eles estão sujeitos a desaparecerem sim, e isso acontece com bastante frequencia até. Entretanto a sugestão no final é muito boa.

Comment: @Math Pois é. Eu também não acho que essa afirmação faz sentido, mas  isso não impede a versão nova que ele sugeriu de ser muito superior à que usamos, na minha opinião.

Comment: @Gabe concordo que a versão nova é melhor

Comment: @Gabe Não ficaria meio "indelicado" afirmar categoricamente que a resposta está errada? A sugestão é muito boa mesmo, se remover a primeira frase.

Comment: @Gabe a mim não me agrada. Está incompleta? Mas uma resposta incompleta é motivo para remover? É que ser baseada em link é.

Comment: @diegofm A sugestão é de que que está "incompleta", não "errada". De qualquer maneira, a gente pode chegar numa palavra melhor.

Comment: @JorgeB. Mas a sugestão do AP não é apagar, ou fazer nada com o post. Ele sugere apenas alterar o teor dos comentários deixados na pergunta, reforçando que a resposta fica mais completa com todo o conteúdo nela, ao invés de apontar pra a (questionável) efemeridade da referência externa

Comment: @Gabe nós não estamos a falar das perguntas sinalizadas como "resposta apenas por link"? Estou confuso agora.

Comment: @Gabe vê a minha resposta.

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu vi sua resposta e não acho que nós estamos concordando sobre o que exatamente o AP sugeriu

Comment: **A minha intenção é somente melhorar a mensagem passada pela comunidade.** Estou apenas a propor que a comunidade use mensagens diferentes e tenho noção do funcionamento da comunidade em relação aos links na resposta.

Comment: Para mim essa discussão ficou improdutiva, pq tá misturando dois conceitos tanto na pergunta quanto nas respostas e comentários. O sistema me parece em ordem, e a mensagem automática adequada. O problema que eu vejo é o **mau uso ocasional** da mensagem automática em casos que o link é só complemento. Creio que se é o caso, deve ser tratado pontualmente. O ponto levantado pelo autor é justo e faz sentido, só que não como generalização (e é aí que a pergunta gerou uma certa rejeição no meu ver). Seria o caso de acharmos o ponto de equilibrio.

Comment: @Bacco Essa é a resposta à minha pergunta/sugestão. Pode escrever para eu a aceitar?

Comment: @Bacco Se bem que eu não tenho a certeza que a mensagem atual seja a melhor. Mas se essa for a decisão maioritária, tudo bem...

Comment: Postei como resposta, mas fique à vontade para votar como achar melhor. Eu não só acho que respostas só com link sejam ruins, como já vi muitos problemas com isso. Acho que os comentários são o lugar para ajuda com apenas link (sou a favor de ajudar seja lá como for, claro).

Comment: Ofato da pergunta ter várias edições mudando o conteúdo não ajudou a discussão ser produtiva. No fundo acho até que a pergunta poderia ser fechada como não clara, porque a ideia nunca foi passada adequadamente, por isso concordo como o @Bacco que a pergunta foi mal recebida por não tratar o problema real. Por ter vários focos, inicialmente parecer um *rant* e mudar muito, as pessoas ficaram sem entender do que se trata. Eu participei de pelo menos 3 debates fora daqui para tentar entender do que trata a pergunta e as edições só piorou a percepção de que nem o autor sabia do que queria tratar.

Comment: **Nota:** Não acho que a pergunta/debate seja duplicado, o problema é que foram misturados alguns assuntos e confundiu um pouco, acho que talvez deva ser fechada (não sei qual o melhor), mas não como duplicata.

Comment: @bigown Há algum motivo por não me ter convidado para o debate? Melhor que ninguém eu poderia explicar a minha intenção. Peço desculpa se a minha pergunta/sugestão causou transtorno para os moderadores. Exatamente pelo fato de ter apercebido que a minha pergunta era um rant inicialmente, editei-a para o deixar de ser. Pois tenho noção que esse tipo de perguntas não costumam ser bem recebidas pela comunidade. Mas eu acho que sempre manti fiel a minha ideia e que o conteúdo da minha pergunta/sugestão sempre transmitiu a mesa ideia: **a mensagem não é a ideal**.

Comment: @BrunoCosta em um deles não, era só ter aparecido no chat, em outros eram privados mesmo. Todas contestações foram colocadas aqui e cada vez que tentou melhorar acabou ficando mais confuso sobre o que queria. Não causou transtorno, faz parte ter esses debates no meta, não é um problema, só que havia uma oportunidade boa para ter algo mais produtivo e acabou não acontecendo.No fim vai ficar de positivo que precisa informar melhor o problema do "só link".Agora ficou + claro, mas o fato de ter que passar por várias edições (e acho que mudou bem o que havia inicialmente) indica que era "não claro"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creio que a discussão como um todo ficou um pouco improdutiva, pois acabaram se misturando dois conceitos tanto na pergunta quanto nas respostas e comentários.

Pensando no mecanismo do sistema, com a resposta enlatada de que "links externos podem desaparecer", me parece tudo em ordem, e a mensagem automática adequada, pois de fato os destinos dos links somem pelas mais variadas razões.

Por outro lado, vejo ocasionalmente o mau uso da mensagem automática, em casos onde a resposta esboça uma solução e o link é só complemento. O ponto levantado pelo autor é justo e faz sentido nestes casos, pois o "enlatado" está orientando errado.

É aí que a pergunta gerou uma certa rejeição no meu ver, por ter talvez generalizado um problema legítimo, que existe, mas não é do sistema em si, apenas do seu mau uso.

**Lembrando que** nada impede de se selecionar "não são necessários comentários" na fila, assim evitando a mensagem automática, deixando para fazer um comentário melhor "manualmente" nestes casos. A discussão do autor se focou na mensagem incorreta, não me pareceu crítica ao fechamento, e sim à justificativa inadequada no fechamento.

Seria o caso de acharmos um ponto de equilíbrio, usando com mais atenção a ferramenta atual, e também tomando uma atitude nos casos em que a aplicação é inadequada, nem que seja com um "contra-comentário", ou uma flag de "não construtivo", e isto vale para todas as mensagens "enlatadas".

Comment: Bacco mas era mesmo isso que eu tentei esclarecer e não consegui. Se for só para respostas que realmente estejam incompletas é uma coisa. Mas mesmo assim quem é você para dizer que está incompleta ou não? Para mim pode estar e para você não e vice-versa. Eu acho que na verdade isto não vai trazer nada de bom, com excepção de alguns casos.

Comment: @JorgeB. Entendo que só link é sempre problema. Se tem algo a mais, cabe sempre sugerir melhora, em vez de usar o enlatado. Concordo em votar pra fechar, mas sem usar o "não poste somente links", como disse o autor. Tem sempre a opção de "Não são necessários comentários" e dá postar um "manualmente", sem o enlatado. Editei a resposta para tentar esclarecer.

Comment: Bacco a minha ideia vai de encontro com a última edição (penúltima agora) do @GuilhermeNacimento

Comment: @JorgeB. eu votei na do Guilherme tb, só respondi pq eu acho que todo mundo tentou explicar pro autor que tem que ser assim, mas não deram muita atenção para o que podia ser aproveitado do que ele disse. Creio que dê pra aproveitar coisas tanto das respostas dadas, quanto da proposta dele, sem mudar o sistema. E eu gosto dessa idéia de reforçar a falta de qualidade como motivo pra mudança, acho mais educativo dó que dizer que o problema é só link (mas nem por isso aceitando o só link). Não acho que precisemos mudar o enlatado, mas nem sempre precisamos nos contentar só com o texto pronto.

Comment: Sim claro, mas a pergunta anda à volta de mudar o enlatado, basta ver pela resposta do próprio AP. E com esse assunto eu não concordo.

Comment: Só para complementar o original é este: "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes." Não digo que não podemos mudar o texto como acharmos melhor, mas a intenção original da rede era passar essa mensagem.

Comment: @bigown mas está tão bem conseguido o texto, para quê mudar?

Comment: @JorgeB. eu tenho que olhar todos os lados :P

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu considerei que não, dai ter trazido esta sugestão a debate...

Answer (score 5):

Olha não me entenda mal, esse assunto já foi debatido, acho que é de muito valor se pesquisar as postagens mais antigas do META sobre o assunto, tal como:

- [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/3635)
- [Perguntas pedindo indicação de ferramentas online](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2226/3635)
- [O que fazer com perguntas que pedem recursos externos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/577/3635)
- [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/3635) (veja esta [resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1914/3635))
- [Qual o recomendável? Usar o Stack Snippet ou outra ferramenta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4204/3635)

Como pode ver o assunto em sua maioria já foi debadito de várias formas, não foi uma decisão "unilateral", ou uma decisão de alguns usuários aleatória e nem uma decisão da comunidade Stack Exchange (rede site ou qualquer coisa assim), foi uma analise feita com o tempo por diversos usuários, o problema começou a ser mais notado no ano de 2012, quando o Stack Overflow em inglês começou a ficar grande e perguntas de 2009 apresentavam links que não funcionavam, não foi uma ideia para "evangelizar" como errado.

A sugestão não diz para não postar links externos, você pode e deve postar, mas também deve copiar o máximo de conteúdo e explicar ele de preferencia, mesmo que uma explicação breve.

Sobre Stack Snippet vs jsfiddle, uma coisa que as pessoas usam muito mal é o Stack Snippet, as pessoas o usam como se ele fosse um formatador de código, o que não é verdade, ele é uma ferramenta tipo **"fiddle"** que reproduz e mostra o código ao mesmo tempo, se o código não irá fazer nada nem tem porque usar ele, use a formatação normal e pronto, agora sobre o jsfiddle, não existe nenhum problema em apontar links para o jsfiddle, desde que você poste o código igualmente de maneira funcional na pergunta, mesmo que sem usar o Stack Snippet.

Eu pessoalmente só uso o jsfiddle se ele tiver uma funcionalidade ausente no Stack Snippet, mas como disse ainda sim copio o código para a pergunta, mas o importante é entender, se o Stack Snippet atende as funcionalidades então não vejo porque usar um recurso externo.

### Sobre o problema da mensagem:

Sobre trocar a mensagem:

> Por favor inclua informação do recurso mencionado, ele pode deixar de existir.

Por:

> A sua resposta está incompleta. Por favor inclua o conteúdo do recurso que considera relevante, de forma a completar a sua resposta.

**Eu não concordo**, isso porque não vejo problema algum na mensagem atual, o problema é aquela situação de que *para uma pessoa soa de uma maneira* e *para outra soa de outra maneira*

Tenho quase certeza que a chance do autor da resposta se sentir ofendido (ou qualquer coisa assim) é maior se você disser que a resposta dele está incompleta, isso eu digo como opinião, pois tenho um bom tempo de participação no site e mesmo sendo educado muitas vezes fui interpretado mal.

Todavia comentários **mais diretos** com uma breve explicação do motivo do problema, como *"ele pode deixar de existir"* funcionaram na maioria (comigo todas as vezes), se disser que está incompleta é provavelmente que gere um debate/discussão ou até um desafeto.

Em resumo acho que a mensagem esta boa da maneira que é (apenas uma opinião).

Comment: Eu compreendi o seu comentário e admito que usei mal o *Stack Snippet*, obrigado por ter deixado um comentário a explicar o que eu fiz de errado. Obrigado também por ter deixado bastante referencias para outras pergutnas do genero desta.

Comment: @BrunoCosta não se preocupe você não fez nada de errado, as ferramentas realmente nem sempre são intuitivas mesmo, estamos aqui para ajudar e orientar também ;)

Comment: Detesto quando alguém posta alguma resposta de PHP com um Snippet. As vezes eu clico de propósito, pensando: "Talvez a SE criou um sandbox de PHP e eu não estou sabendo"

Comment: @WallaceMaxters então esse é outro problema, mas é bem valido, eu até criei um debate a algum tempo http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2363/3635 todavia é complicado resolver esse impasse (também em http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247424/198279)

Comment: Exatamente a minha opinião, essa última edição.

Comment: Exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78561/101

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o navbar do bootstrap, veja aqui:

- http://bootsnav.danurstrap.com

---

É deste tipo de resposta que está a falar Bruno Costa?

Esse tipo de resposta é normalmente sinalizada como de baixa qualidade e poderá ser excluída com a notificação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É isso que de certeza você lê muito por ai, e se for este o caso eu acho que a mensagem se deve manter a mesma.

Comment: Sim, mas também acontece a resposta estar na direcção certa mas ainda assim incompleta. Eu estou-me a referir a casos onde normalmente a resposta exige uma explicação detalhada.

Comment: @BrunoCosta então a tua pergunta é se a resposta já tem conteúdo e também um link?

Comment: @BrunoCosta é que eu fiquei confuso agora com o comentário do Gabe. É que se for uma resposta que já tenha conteúdo sem ser o link, eu concordo com outro tipo de abordagem.

Comment: Eu nao sei quanto à opinião do Gabe. O que eu quero mesmo é acabar com este tipo de comentário porque não o considero relevante nem produtivo. Não me estava a referir à mensagem quando a resposta é só um link mas pelo que estou a ler ela também pode ser melhorada. Estes comentários transmitem uma mensagem que não está correta ou que não é o ponto relevante.

Answer (score 1):

Para além da minha proposta de melhorar os comentários deixados nas respsotas. Gostava também então de sugerir uma frase diferente para a mensagem atual, quando uma resposta contém apenas um link.

> **Esta é uma resposta apenas por link (e não um spam)**
>
> A sua resposta está incompleta. Para manter uma boa qualidade de
>   respostas [a comunidade considera necessário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links) que inclua a informação
>   relevante das fontes que consultou na sua resposta.

Comment: Faço minhas as palavras do @Guilherme, esse comentário ia criar ainda mais polémica. Afinal quem é você para me dizer se está incompleta ou não? Qual é a linha que separa uma resposta incompleta de uma completa? Acho que como está, está muito melhor, claro que isto é só a minha opinião.

Comment: @JorgeB. Compreendo a perspectiva.